# CI / CD pipeline for legacy ASP.NET Web Forms application

Tags: asp.net, azure-devops, webforms, msbuild, cicd

I am taking over a legacy ASP.NET Web Forms application written a long time ago. The application does not come with a .csproj file or a VS .sln file. All DLL libraries are simply added to the bin folder and referenced directly in code. All CS classes are added to the app_code folder and referenced in code.

We are trying to integrate this site to make use of CI / CD pipelines but it has been very challenging. Part of it is because we cant make use of MSBuild because we don't have a project file or a solution file.

I was wondering if anyone has been in a similar situation before. What would be the best way to create a project and / or solution file for this? Do we need to have both a project file and a solution file? Any guides out there you can point to on how to do this?

I hope my question is clear. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -2):

> The application does not come with a .csproj file or a VS .sln file

That is normal for a asp.net web site. No sln, or project files are required.

Of course that means you do NOT open the site by using open project, but open the site by using open web site. As such, no csproj or even a project (sln) file is required, or should even exist.

> All DLL libraries are simply added to the bin folder and referenced directly in code

Again, that's quite normal for  web site.

For a web site "application", then references to external libraies and .dll's (assmeblies) is much like desktop. You add these refrences. then at deploy time, visual stuido will build, compile, and move all the .dll's into the bin folder for you. And you even have options to "merge" such .dll's into one .dll at publish time.

At this point in time, if you can open the site site, view a web page, and then say right click, and view code, then you are in great shape.

However, it is ALSO possible that your web site folder is the RESULT of a asp.net web site "application". If that is the case, then the web site will NOT have the code behind, since Visual studio did the compile. When you use a asp.net web site (not a asp.net web site application), then both the markup  pages, and the code behind pages should exist. This ALSO means that the web site (IIS) does the compile of code, and NOT visual studio.

so, the only detail you need to determine?

Does the web site have BOTH the markup pages, and ALSO has the source code (code behind) pages? If you do not have the code behind pages, then you don't have a web site, but have the "results" of a web site application publish. This means you don't have the code behind (source code).

But, opening a web site from visual studio does not need nor require a project file, nor does it require  sln file.

so, I guess the base question (that will quite much answer all of the above points and questions?

do you see + have the code behind pages on that site? Since if you do not, then you have to go find and get the original project used to publish that web site application, and without as such, you not only missing the source code, but all of the references etc. that are saved in the project file(s).

> What would be the best way to create a project and / or solution file for this?

Gee, if this is a web site and not  "application", then you may well not want to do this (at least not yet). There are quite a few advantages of keeping and using a web site as opposed to a web site application, and one issue will be setup of all the references.

Also, web servers tend to be far more tolerent of accepting a web site, then a web site application. (for example, it boatloads easier to copy or ftp a web site to a sub site in a folder on the web server.

If the main startup page is the main page of the web site, then it without question a lot easier to say convert, and open the folder as a project, and thus the sln file will be created. However, quite a few assumptions will have been made based on "application" vs non application, and if that's how the system was setup, then little advantages exist to now try and convert to a web application.

The other huge advantage? with a web site, you can modify one line of code, save, and you are done.

With a web site application, you change just one line of code, and you now have to re-publish the WHOLE site. So, while I without question prefer the application road? You noted in your post that you want to keep agile development, and if that is your goal, then hands down keeping this as a web site is a far better choice. You can change one line of code, save, and if that page + code is moved to the server, you are done.

so, a application is far more formalized, but quite much kills the agile development goal you noted in your post.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding on the emphasis of the question.  I do have a web site and not a website application. I can see the code behind, make changes, ftp etc.. without having to rebuild / publish the whole site. I am asking what the best practice is for making use of CI/CD pipelines with this kind of legacy asp.net web site. How do I make sure that a change in code behind did not break the site without manually opening the site in Visual Studio and running it and making use of MSBuild and command line tools.

Comment: Well converting to web application means that each page needs to be modified (page directive). That's why I suggested to keep as web site. Such a change to web app is not automated. And if you change one line of code in one page and it compiles - then that's about the best test. So the current setup is clearly more forgiving and agile then converting to web app. No question web app will better catch code changes that potential could break the site, but you losing agile development by going down that road - no, didn't miss understand question at all. Penalties exist with web app, but preferred

Comment: > And if you change one line of code in one page and it compiles - then that's about the best test.

We do that manually though. There is no automation in process and that's what we are trying to create so we don't have to do this manually.

Comment: 100% agree it not all hugs and perfect. A change to code quite much suggests the developer does at least compile the code at that point in time - and web site does that with less hassle and efforts then web app. Not great, but this still suggests that it less effort, less time and less time to simple change the code and see if it compiles. Web site edit, change publish cycle is far more agile then right? A full compile, and testing, resolving of references? Hands down web app, but then that's not very agile! So, which is more valuable to you? Your choice.

Comment: Downside of web form apps is they don't lend themselves say to unit testing. but then again, if you looking to be really agile, you often forgo unit testing anyway, right? I mean, how agile do you want to be here? Hands down prefer to give up  SOME agile parts here, and thus use web apps. (but it far more pain to make a simple code change). (full web site publish required). So, less agile , but far more compile time checks of references, and better chance of catching code that could break site. You have to consider time + cost + budgets to convert to web app - it not automatic.